# Issue to call setMessage() on ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm having an issue creating a ProgressDialog in my **onCreateDialog()** method.
The code is as follows:

```
Dialog dialog;
switch(id){
    case CONNECTING:
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Connecting").setTitle("");
        return dialog;
```

Eclipse throws me an error setMessage wouldn't be a valid Method of the type ProgressDialog, though I expect it to be there since the documentation for API8 (which I use) says so.
AFAIK the instantiation should be possible since ProgressDialog ihnerits from Dialog right?

Can someone help me at this? It's really weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code to:

```
Dialog dialog;
switch(id){
    case CONNECTING:
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        ((ProgressDialog)dialog).setMessage("Connecting");
        dialog.setTitle("");
        return dialog;
```

Alliteratively, you can change dialog to type ProgresssDialog if you are always returning a ProgresssDialog, but I doubt it.

Comment: ok that's a bit of a hack, but working... thank you. Do you think it's worth reporting a bug for this since it shouldn't be this way should it?

Comment: Its not a bug. You are accessing a method of an extended class of Dialog. You are doing different things to an object of type Dialog, so if you are using a ProgressDialog in one of those cases, you need to tell it to process dialog as type ProgresssDialog and not Dialog. Make sense?

Comment: well yes, but e.g. I am able do call ArrayList<> methods even when I declared the attribute as a List<>

Comment: @JulianKessel Not if `List` doesn't support it. Try calling `trimToSize` on a `List`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `Dialog` doesn't have a setMessage method. Which is the type of the variable dialog.

Edit:
This line:

```
dialog.setMessage("Connecting").setTitle("");
```

Also looks wrong since setMessage() returns void.

Comment: You didn't answer the question. ProgressDialog does have a setMessage() method( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#setMessage(java.lang.CharSequence) ). However you were right about setMessage returns void.

Comment: @Spencer Yes but Dialog does not. The dialog variable is of type Dialog which has no setMessage method.